# What are the missing two letters in the following series and why?

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

W A T _ T L I T F S A _

Guess the missing letters.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think I got it.

> M and W  : The series of letters is an acronym of the title!

Answer (score 13):

Answer is

> **W**     What
>  **A**     are
>  **T**     the
>  _     missing   // letter **'M'**
>  **T**     two
>  **L**     letters
>  **I**     in
>  **T**     the
>  **F**     following
>  **S**     series
>  **A**     and
>  _     why?     // letter **'W'**