# What Missing Letters Goes In The Blanks And Why?

Tags: letter-sequence

Here's a letter sequence I made. Can you figure out what missing letters goes in the blanks?

**TW, GM, SL, SG, __, ET, SB, __, __**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The missing letters are

> **NI**, **DA**, **YW**. The letter pairs are the last and first letter of each word in this question's title.

Comment: Okay then, that was fast...  I was thinking about initials.  Wrong tree.

Comment: I had seen [this question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16106/riddles-puzzles-having-answer-hidden-in-the-question/16112#16112) recently, so this sort of thing was on my mind.

Comment: Good job! That was fast! ETMOTA- So funny!

Comment: good observation!

Comment: [This question](http://www.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/13070/what-are-the-missing-two-letters-in-the-following-series-and-why) is also similar.